# django -- Display foreign key relation value in django template

Tags: django-models, django-templates

I have a ForeignKey relation between two models and I would like to show the related value in the web page

models.py

```
class ndcc_template(models.Model):
     created_by  = models.ForeignKey(to=myperso_user, related_name='created_by_user', verbose_name='Créé par', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False, null=True)

class myperso_user(AbstractUser):
     location = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
```

template.html

```
<h4>--- {{ ctx_form.created_by.value }} ---</h4>
```

At this point I would like to view the user_name and not the user_ID

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: In general this should be intuitive, here's an example where `user_name` is the name of the field you want to display:
`<h4>--- {{ instance.created_by.user_name }} ---</h4>`
But what is `ctx_form` in your question? A form? What's the corresponding view? We'll need more context to help you.

Comment: ctx_form is the form passed in context

The view is the following
`
def tpl_edit(request, slug):
    msgaction= ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        tpl = get_object_or_404(ndcc_template, slug=slug)
    else:
        tpl = ndcc_template.objects.get(slug=slug)
        form = ndcc_template_Form(instance=tpl)

    return render(request, template_name='ndcc_tpl/tpl.html', context={'NDCC_module_name': NDCC_MOD_NAME, 'ctx_tpl_slug': slug, 'ctx_msgaction': msgaction, 'ctx_form': form})
`

Comment: I just tried the following whitout success
`
<h4>--- {{ ctx_form.created_by.username }} ---</h4>
`

Comment: Another approach would be to add the desired value to the template via context.

Comment: Thanks Jovan.V It is finally the slution I use to have only static information in one page (I splitted the visualisation view and the change view to simplify that)
Thanks to all for your help